# Add a year to a date (and deal with leap year)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Using "Mongodb" shell, I have to compute the date of the day + one year.
I can add 365 days do the current date, but I'll be wrong with leap year.
Example:

```
print(new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365)));
```

We are "2015-06-22". This "date + 365 = 2016-06-21" :)
I have not found any date function on Mongodb. How do you deal with leap year?

Comment: So would `March 11, 2015` + 1 year become `March 11, 2016` (As it's the same day, but the next year). Or is your definition of a year `365.242 days`. Why not just add seconds? `31536000`. By the way, you can use Javascript date object in mongoshell as mongo uses javascript. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: So, what is `+1 year` if we are the 29th of February ?

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you just want it to be the same date for the next year you can use

```
var a = Date()
a.setFullYear(a.getFullYear() + 1)
```

As Sylvain Leroux points out you will have to handle the edge case of the 29th of February by default it will change to the first of March when you add a year. This will not happen if you add a year to march 1st of the year before a leap year.

Comment: Thx, it works! I forgot we can use Javascript functions in Mongo shell :p